# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.util.Assert.noNullElements

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-mvc

I upgraded the `spring-web` module version from `5.1.2.RELEASE` to `5.2.4.RELEASE` for my Micronaut application deployed on AWS. I had to upgrade to a more stable version (suggested fix by WhiteSource) as the older version jar was considered to be highly vulnerable from a security standpoint by the WhiteSource tool.

The issue is that most of my application's endpoints worked just fine as they were mainly database queries but I noticed that if I make a REST call, the endpoint fails with the following error:

```
Invocation with requestId [ca31a9a5-35b3-4b52-a955-e304d9021880] failed: org.springframework.util.Assert.noNullElements(java.util.Collection, java.lang.String)java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.util.Assert.noNullElements(java.util.Collection, java.lang.String)
at org.springframework.web.client.HttpMessageConverterExtractor.<init>(HttpMessageConverterExtractor.java:77)
at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate$ResponseEntityResponseExtractor.<init>(RestTemplate.java:988)
at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.responseEntityExtractor(RestTemplate.java:819)
at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.exchange(RestTemplate.java:582)
at com.connector.getToken(Connector.java:58)
```

Downgrading the version is not much of an option as those jars will be rejected/deemed vulnerable by WhiteSource. Is there another workaround/solution for this? Please let me know! Thanks.

Comment: It seems your deployed app still uses the old version, as this method was only added in 5.2

Comment: I ran `gradle dependencies` command and saw that the version was upgraded for `spring-web` as: `org.springframework:spring-web:5.1.2.RELEASE -> 5.2.4.RELEASE` but the parent dependency is still taking the older version - `org.springframework:spring-webmvc:5.1.2.RELEASE`

Comment: You cannot just upgrade one version, you have to upgrade all Spring jars to the specific version (never mix different versions of a framework that will byte you). Also don't blindly trust tools, investigate WHY it is vulnerable and then decide what to do (generally the vulnerability is in a used dependency and often not in Spring itself).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure to upgrade the `spring-core` dependency to 5.2.4.RELEASE as well.

Or rather: Make sure that **all** `spring-` dependencies have the same version number.

Comment: I just upgraded the `spring-web` and `spring-core` dependencies to `5.2.5.RELEASE` versions without upgrading the other spring jars and I don't see the error anymore. The REST call works just fine. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Double check if your pom.xml (or in case of maven multi module, your parent pom.xml) has this code:

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.7.3</version>
    <relativePath/>
</parent>
```

Replace 'version' accordingly to the spring version you're willing to use.