# Power BI integration with Azure AD B2C

Tags: java, powerbi, azure-ad-b2c, powerbi-embedded

I have an application running with Azure AD B2B where the front end is App service (SPA - Angular 11) and the backend is Azure Function app (java). I have Power BI Pro user accounts. I have integrated the Power BI reports into our application.

For Power BI integration, I have referred to the [official documentation here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/developer/embedded/embed-sample-for-customers?tabs=java) and the java code to get the tokens and the embed URL, [from here](https://github.com/microsoft/PowerBI-Developer-Samples/tree/master/Java)

This seems to work fine. (I am using master user and pass to access the reports)

I am now planning to switch to Azure AD B2C. I am using the same application working with B2C. The only thing that does not work is Power BI reports.

I get the below error in the function app, while trying to get the embedded URL of the reports. The method in the sample code can be found in the [java code here](https://github.com/microsoft/PowerBI-Developer-Samples/blob/82763899e19c27de9cbd8eeffc6028e0e726f69a/Java/Embed%20for%20your%20customers/AppOwnsData/src/main/java/com/embedsample/appownsdata/services/PowerBIService.java#L82)

```
2021-06-29T09:46:06.998 [Error] Executed 'Functions.PowerBIEmbeddedToken' (Failed, Id=<id>, Duration=7019ms)
Result: Failure
Exception: NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.util.Assert.noNullElements(Ljava/util/Collection;Ljava/lang/String;)V
Stack: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.microsoft.azure.functions.worker.broker.JavaMethodInvokeInfo.invoke(JavaMethodInvokeInfo.java:22)
    at com.microsoft.azure.functions.worker.broker.JavaMethodExecutorImpl.execute(JavaMethodExecutorImpl.java:54)
    at com.microsoft.azure.functions.worker.broker.JavaFunctionBroker.invokeMethod(JavaFunctionBroker.java:57)
    at com.microsoft.azure.functions.worker.handler.InvocationRequestHandler.execute(InvocationRequestHandler.java:33)
    at com.microsoft.azure.functions.worker.handler.InvocationRequestHandler.execute(InvocationRequestHandler.java:10)
    at com.microsoft.azure.functions.worker.handler.MessageHandler.handle(MessageHandler.java:45)
    at com.microsoft.azure.functions.worker.JavaWorkerClient$StreamingMessagePeer.lambda$onNext$0(JavaWorkerClient.java:92)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.util.Assert.noNullElements(Ljava/util/Collection;Ljava/lang/String;)V
    at org.springframework.web.client.HttpMessageConverterExtractor.<init>(HttpMessageConverterExtractor.java:78)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate$ResponseEntityResponseExtractor.<init>(RestTemplate.java:988)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.responseEntityExtractor(RestTemplate.java:819)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.exchange(RestTemplate.java:582)
    at net.com.techman.service.PowerBIService.getEmbedConfig(PowerBIService.java:81)
    at net.com.techman.service.PowerBIEmbeddedService.fetchEmbeddedToken(PowerBIEmbeddedService.java:45)
    at net.com.techman.function.PowerBIEmbeddedTokenFunction.run(PowerBIEmbeddedTokenFunction.java:44)
    ... 16 more
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an issue with Spring. Update Spring and its dependencies to fix the problem.

Comment: figured out that the issue is with the spring version. refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60997929/java-lang-nosuchmethoderror-org-springframework-util-assert-nonullelements for more details